# Matlab/ Scilab/ R : Creating a block tridiagonal matrix in Scilab

Tags: r, matlab, matrix, scilab

I need to create a block tridiagonal matrix in Scilab. More explicitly I would like to set up a M^2 X M^2 matrix of the format:

```
  B  C   0 ... 0  0 
  D  B   C  0 ... 0 
  0  D   B  C ... 0
  0 ... ... ... ...  
  0  0  ... D  B  C 
  0  0   0 ... D  B
```

where B,C and D are M X M matrices.

I know how to create a block diagonal matrix with help of the "sysdiag" function but I haven't found any reference for easily creating a block tridiagonal one.

By the way given the matrices B,C and D I know how to create the matrix above.

```
 auxA = sysdiag(B,B);
  auxC = C;
  auxD = D;
  for i=1:2*M-1
     auxA = sysdiag(auxA,B);
     auxC = sysdiag(auxC,C);
     auxD = sysdiag(auxD,D);
  end
  A = auxA + [zeros((2*M+1)^2 -(2*M+1),2*M+1) auxC ;zeros(2*M+1,2*M+1) zeros(2*M+1,(2*M+1)^2 -(2*M+1)) ] + [zeros(2*M+1,(2*M+1)^2 -(2*M+1)) zeros(2*M+1,2*M+1); auxD zeros((2*M+1)^2 -(2*M+1),2*M+1)];
```

I would still like to knwo if there is a function that does it directly in Scilab, Matlab or R.
Could someone help me with that please?

All advices are appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Doesn't look like there is.  The only utility I know generating a tri-diagonal matrix, but not with the elements being matrices... only scalars.  However, this submission to MATLAB FEX by John D'Errico is of particular interest: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10603--block--tri-diagonal-matrices

Answer (score 0):

The [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), realized as `.*.` in Scilab, can help. Given M, B, C, D as in your post, Kronecker product with identity matrix creates the block-diagonal matrix like what you'd get with `sysdiag`:

```
eye(M,M).*.B
```

But the Kronecker product can also be taken with other matrices. Put 1s above the main diagonal, and take Kronecker product with C to obtain the C blocks in the desired locations:

```
diag(ones(M-1,1),1).*.C
```

Similarly for D:

```
diag(ones(M-1,1),-1).*.D
```

In one line,

```
A = eye(M,M).*.B + diag(ones(M-1,1),1).*.C + diag(ones(M-1,1),-1).*.D
```

does the job.